# Equivalent to TUpdateSQL in Delphi 2010 dbExpress?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, dbexpress, bde

I am planning to migrate a Delphi 6 BDE application to Delphi 2010...

- First of all, do I have to move away from BDE? (I will but I prefer to do this in stages if possible)
- Second, is dbExpress the best choice? (I am using MS SQL)
- Lastly, is there an equivalent of TUpdateSQL in dbExpress? (or anything else)

I have a lot of codes updating readonly query from within a grid (using TUpdateSQL and ApplyUpdate).

Please help~~~

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** You definitely have to migrate from BDE to [DbExpress](http://edn.embarcadero.com/el/article/28688). BDE is an [obsolete and deprecated](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BDE_Overview) technology.

You can read these articles

- [Migrating BDE Applications to dbExpress](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29106)
- [Migrating Data from TDataSet to SQL DBMS](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examin98.htm)

**2)** DbExpress is a better alternative than BDE to communicate with sql server, however I prefer ADO because is native for SQL Server.

**3)** dbExpress has no component similar to TUpdateSQL, however [Luxene](http://www.luxena.com/manual.aspx?process=dbxext_case_studies&argument=migration) have a TDBXUpdateSQL wich is part from *dbExpress eXtension* components.

You can check also [InstantBDExpress](http://www.ethea.it/eng_instantbdexpress.asp) (*is a component library that enables seamless  migration of old BDE applications to the dbExpress technology*) from [ETHEA](http://www.ethea.it/eng_default.asp)

Bye.

Answer (score 1):

On a TDataSetProvider there is a event called BeforeUpdateRecord which is basicly a more manual way of doing TUpdateSQL

you have to create the SQL your self and then update it.(via TADOQuery etc..)

how ever it has the same basics of old and new values which where in TUpdateSQL

sry this is c++ i don't know dehpli but it basicly the same i think

```
DeltaDS->FieldByName("id")->NewValue;
```

and

```
DeltaDS->FieldByName("id")->OldValue;
```

also you have to set

```
Applied = true;
```

so that it doesn't try to do the update after you have manually done it

here a few links which should help
[About BeforeUpdateRecord](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Provider_TDataSetProvider_BeforeUpdateRecord.html)

if you need any more info just add a comment and ill get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Using the SQLQuery component of dbExpress, one can write 'queries' such as

```
update <table>
set value = :v1
where something = :v2
```

and then one calls the 'execsql' method to physically update the table.

Comment: He's asking about TUpdateSQL component, which allow substitution of SQL generated by the BDE component(TTable, TQuery) for ones written by the developer. It's mostly used for allowing updates on queries with joins.

Comment: And when I say 'updates' read: insert, delete and update commands.

Comment: One can't insert/delete/update with a join. Only 'select' statements can have a join.

Comment: We're talking about BDE components, and yes they can - if you create the SQL to Insert,Update and Delete on the query object and put it on a TUpdateSQL. When the bde component get a Post commanded, it uses the SQL on the TUpdateSQL component to write the data to database

Answer (score 0):

Using ClientDatasets and providers, you can use a TDatasetProvider with a generic OnUpdateRecord(?, don't remember the exact name now) handler and make it uses the
sqls you used on TUpdateSQL.

Just an idea, in the case you cannot use 3rd party components....